# ajax PHP form validation display error massage when no succes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this question was probabley asked before but from what i have searched I couldnt find the answer I was looking for.

This is the issue:

I have a form that is sent via ajax $post to a php file called `upload_data.php`.
This file calls a php function called `insert_data` the php function contains a simple check to see if the `$idNo` variable already exists.

Now till now everything works great.
My question is how can I show the user the error that i receive from the php function.

this are the files:

**ajax call:**

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload_data.php',
                data: fd,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                      $('#error').append(data);

                }
            });
```

**upload_data.php**

```
$upload_dir = "uploads/vitur-sodiut/";
$img = $_POST['hidden_data'];
$idNo = $_POST['idno'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];



$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . "" . $idNo . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';


$suc = new Form;
$suc->insert_data($lname, $fname, $file, $idNo);
```

**insert_data function**

```
public function insert_data($lname, $fname, $file, $idNo){

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM vitur_sodiut WHERE idno=?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1,  $idNo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
    if( ! $row)
    {



        $query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO vitur_sodiut (lname, fname, file, idno) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
        $query->bindparam(1, $lname);
        $query->bindparam(2, $fname);
        $query->bindparam(3, $file);
        $query->bindparam(4, $idNo);



        try {
        $query->execute();
            if (!$query) { //בודק אם הנתונים הוכנסו למנ
                echo "Failure conncting db!";
            }else{
                $success["body"] = "You request just sending to the server ...";
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", true, 200); 
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        echo'value already exists in the table';
    }
}
```

This is a snapshot of my console. what we see there is the data var from the ajax call. the result from the php function is out of the array.

[image]

Comment: an option is to get a json in response, and check the flag that whether the status is success or failure (send that status, from ajax only). And based on the ajax response show the proper message.

Comment: as long as you return nothing else except that message (and not all your other debugging code) then you should simply be able to insert that into the DOM as you seem to be already doing in the same. If you want to return a number of different messages / pieces of data in the repsonse, and then have the JS decide which bit(s) to display, then you need to collect everything up into an array or object in PHP, and then encode that to JSON, so the JS code can pick which property of the response to use in the page. Plenty of examples of that online already.

Comment: But as i see it the ajax call is successfull. the "error" is in the php script

Comment: @ADyson I want to return nothing except the massage. the array is still showing in the DOM. This is the result I get In `#error` div  `uploads/vitur-sodiut/303748891.pngarray(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["fname"]=> string(6) "דוד" ["lname"]=> string(3) "sus" ["idno"]=> string(9) "303748891" ["file"]=> string(34) "uploads/vitur-sodiut/323213021.png" ["time"]=> string(19) "2017-09-28 10:02:25" } value already exists in the table` the last sentence is the output i want, how can i prevent the array to be exported?

Comment: That's because you wrote `var_dump($row);` which dumps the array to the output stream. You also have the output of `print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';` right at the start of that string as well. Simply remove both those lines. Sorry I thought it would be obvious that these lines were causing output, they're quite basic PHP commands.

Comment: Also these lines `$success["body"] = "You request just sending to the server ...";
                header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", true, 200); ` seem to be redundant. The first one you never use the value for anything else, so it's pointless. And the second one is the default HTTP response anyway. You only need to set this header if you want the response to be something different (e.g. Bad Request or something)

Comment: that definatley solved my question. thank you! this is my code now. is ther a more elegant way to do it? comparing the var to the string dosent seem right to me...

Comment: that definatley solved my question. thank you! this is my code now. is ther a more elegant way to do it? comparing the var to the string dosent seem right to me...   `
                    success: function(data) {
  
                        if(data == 'value already exists in the table') {  
                          $('#error').append(data);
                        }else{
                            alert('the form was uploaded');`

Answer (score -1):

To show errors from php to ajax call update your ajax success call back function as below.

```
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.error==true) //error is a variable from php as a flag
     {
       $('#error').append(data);
      }
   }
```

data will be returned from php. so send the data from php to ajax call as a json and update the flas as true and store in data when ever their is an error.

Comment: this would work if the PHP was returning JSON, but it isn't. So on its own this answer won't solve the problem.

Comment: @ADyson: In my answer  i have mentioned that return the data from php as a json.

Comment: Yes but you need to show it explicitly, don't assume that OP knows how to do this, if they haven't demonstrated already that they understand. From the comments above it seems they don't have much understanding of the code, since they didn't seem to know which lines were causing output to be written. A good answer needs to solve the problem completely, not just parts of it.